# Does memory consumption affect execution time?

Tags: language-agnostic

Let's say we execute the same program **P** on two different machines. The first machine has, for example, 20% of its memory already in use by other programs, while the second has 90% already occupied. Assuming **P** has all the memory it needs to run on both machines, will it do so faster on the first machine?

Answer (score 1):

That will depend on a couple of things:

- If free memory is fragmented or not.
- If free memory is real memory or virtual (swap being used).
- The memory allocator strategy the program is using.

And probably it will depend on some other stuff too.